# Querying last row of sorted column where value is less than specific amount from parquet file

Tags: pyspark, parquet, python-polars, fastparquet, duckdb

I have a large parquet file where the data in one of the columns is sorted.  A very simplified example is below.

```
    X   Y
0   1   Red
1   5   Blue
2   8   Green
3   12  Purple
4   15  Blue
5   17  Purple
```

I am interested in querying the last value of column Y given that X is less than some amount in the most efficient way possible using python.

I am guaranteed that column X is sorted in ascending order.

As an example, given that X is less than 11, I would expect a Y value of "Green".

I have tried the following:

```
columns='Y'
filters=[('X','<',11]

pd.read_parquet('my_data.parquet',filters=filters,columns=columns).tail(1)
```

The code above "works" but I am hoping optimizations are possible as this query is run 1M+ times per day.

The parquet file is too large to be read into memory.

I cannot put a starting value for column "X", as there is no guarantee of the size of the gap between values of X.  For example, if I were to require "X > 10 and X < 11" I would not get a value for Y returned.

I was hoping given the fact the data is sorted there is a way to optimize this.

I am open to using DuckDB or some other library to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's what [`.search_sorted()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.search_sorted.html#polars-expr-search-sorted) is for.

You can also use [`.scan_parquet()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.scan_parquet.html#polars-scan-parquet) to lazy load the data instead of `.read_parquet()`

You may need to use `when/then` to handle the case of the first row being a match - and using index `0` instead of `row - 1` - or the case of there being no match (if that's possible.)

```
(pl.scan_parquet("search.parquet")
   .select(
      pl.col("Y")
        .take(pl.col("X").search_sorted(11, side="left") - 1)
).collect()
```

```
shape: (1, 1)
┌───────┐
│ Y     │
│ ---   │
│ str   │
╞═══════╡
│ Green │
└───────┘
```

Comment: Thank you this is an order of magnitude faster!